# Structural isomers of hexaammineiron(III) hexacyanidocobaltate(III)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, isomers

> Find the number of structural isomers of $\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_6][Co(CN)_6]}$

This was a question solved by my teacher as follows:

The $\ce{CN}$ will show linkage isomerism while $\ce{NH_3}$ and $\ce{CN}$ will show coordination isomerism.

We will now consider cases of coordination isomerism and then use linkage isomerism.

- $\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_6][Co(CN)_6]}\rightarrow 7$ isomers(due to linkage isomerism of $\ce{CN}$)
- $\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_5(CN)][Co(CN)_5(NH_3)]}\rightarrow 2\times 6=12$
- $\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_4(CN)_2][Co(CN)_4(NH_3)_2]}\rightarrow 3\times 5=15$
- $\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_3(CN)_3][Co(CN)_3(NH_3)_3]}\rightarrow$ not counted.

The further $3$ cases are similar to the first $3$ and will result in the same number of isomers. Hence the answer is $2\times(7+12+15)=68$.

Why is $\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_3(CN)_3][Co(CN)_3(NH_3)_3]}$ "not counted"?

I feel that isomers due to $\ce{CN}$ showing linkage isomerism are perfectly valid. Please correct me if I'm wrong and sorry if the question is too trivial.

Comment: Firstly, there is a typo in your solution. It should be 2*(7+12+15)=68. Also I feel that the compound which you mentioned has to be counted but only once.(in the sense that it wouldn't be inside the *2. And just 4*4=16 isomers in the case. Giving a total of 68+16=84 isomers

Comment: We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field due to issues it gives rise to; see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Comment: @user600016 Sorry for the typo, fixed it. And for the second part of your comment, that's exactly what I want to say.

Comment: @Zenix what should be the ideal title then?

Comment: @user600016 Did you check out the meta post in my previous comment? There's a general consensus here that we try to avoid MathJax and $\LaTeX$ in titles due to *URL slug*. [Answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/150/50406) by ex-moderator of site sums it nicely.

Comment: @Zenix Oh my bad. I think in MSE that is the case but not sure again

Comment: @user600016 You are right, it's not the case in MSE, rather we generally edit the titles and add MathJax. Here, `\ce{^}` paves problem, which is not the case in MSE ;)

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Rule of thumb for the same chemical compound appearing both in title and in the body: whenever possible, use chemical *names* in the title and chemical *formulas* in the body. This way you not only avoid problems with the search engines incorrectly parsing MathJax, but also gain better search coverage for the future visitors, sort of kindergarten-level CEOing.

Comment: @andselisk Thank you for that! I will keep that in mind in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer:

> In the following case:
>   $$\ce{[Fe(NH_3)_3(CN)_3][Co(CN)_3(NH_3)_3]}$$
>   Both the constituent entities are neutral and hence will exist independently, and thus will not form isomers of the original compound.

Comment: Pfft, it still could be a compound not necessarily a mixture. CN ligands are bridging, so most of reasoning in all this makes little practical sense.

Comment: @Mithoron Could you elaborate as to how $\ce{CN}$ ligands being a bridging states that the above will exist as a compound? Please keep in in mind I'm only 16 and have just started learning Coordination Chemistry- all I have learnt is nomenclature and Isomerism; no CFT and so on.

Comment: Well if the two metallic centers were connected (Fe-CN-Co) then they wouldn't exist independently. Of course formula would be different, but I'm talking about practical aspect here, maybe pointlessly as such isomer counting has little to do with realism and more with training in 3D thinking.

Comment: @Mithoron I guess that's what my teacher had in mind. This was just after we had been explained all the types of isomerizations.